# How to make <Footer> use 100% width of the webpage

Tags: html, css, footer

Here is my HTML:

```
 <body>
     <nav>
       <div id="navBar">
        <ul> 
         <li><a href="esileht.html">ESILEHT</a></li>
         <li><a href="uudised.html">UUDISED</a></li>
         <li><a href="ülevaated.html">ÜLEVAATED/ARVUSTUSED</a></li>
         <li><a href="login.html" id="logimine">LOGI SISSE</a></li>
        </ul>
       </div>
     </nav>
     <div class="content">
      <div id="logo">
       <img src="http://i.imgur.com/Y4g5MOM.png" alt="Gaming website logo" height="84" width="540"/>
      </div>
      <div id="tervitus">
       <h3 id="tere">TERE TULEMAST</h3>
      </div>  
     </div>
     <div class="artikkel">
      <p>check check</p>
     </div>
     <footer>&copy;2014 Janno.</footer>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
#navBar{
 width: 100%;
 float: left;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 background-color: #000000;
 left: 0;
 min-width:760px;
}

#navBar ul{
 list-style:none;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

#navBar li{
 float: left;
}

#navBar li a:link , a:visited{
 font-size: 90%;
 display: block;
 color: #ffffff;
 padding: 20px 25px;
 font: 18px "open sans", sans-serif;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-decoration: none;
}

#navBar li a:hover{
 background-color: #F0F0F0;
 color: #000000;
 text-decoration: none;
}

#logimine{

}

body{
 margin: 15px;
 padding: 15px;
 background-color: #F0F0F0;
 min-width: 700px;
}

.content, .artikkel{
 max-width: 65%;
 margin: 1em auto;
 box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.8);
 background-color: #ffffff;
 padding: 3em;
 padding-bottom: 350px;
 margin-bottom:50px;
}

#tervitus{
 background-color: black;
 color: white;
 font: 18px "open sans", sans-serif;
 font-weight: bold;
}

#tere{
 margin-left: 5px;
}

#logo{

}

#regnupp{
 color: blue; /*miks see valge on muidu*/
}

.uudised{
 max-width: 65%;
 margin: 4em auto;
 box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.8);
 background-color: #ffffff;
 padding: 3em;
 padding-bottom: 350px;
 margin-bottom:50px;
}

.uudised{
 padding-left: 115px;
}

.uudised img{
 float: left;
 width: 100px;
 margin-left: -75px;
}

.uudised p, h2{
 margin-left: 50px;
}

.uudised hr{
 margin-top: 50px;
 margin-bottom: 50px;
}

footer {
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0 auto -40px;
 width: 100%;
 padding-top: 5px;
 padding-bottom: 5px;
 font-weight:300;
 color:#ffffff;
 background-color:#000000;  
}
```

If I understand correctly, the `<footer>`, when using `width: 100%;` looks like the width of the `<body>` element, so I tried quite a few things and nothing. This is my first try at a webpage, so is there anything I can do, to have the `<footer>` use the entirety of the page width, without drastically changing everything?

Comment: your fiddle is not working

Comment: Your link to a JsFiddle isn't working!

Comment: Read the help centre about asking questions, post your code here too - helps to avoid all the above comments

Comment: Edited my post, sorry, was away for a while.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that firstly your css is set up properly such as:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

then your footer css should be something like this:

```
.footer {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 120px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

This should work obvious then your html should be something like:

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="footer">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: why won't you use the `<footer>` element itself?

Comment: Either one is valid HTML

Comment: @Paulie_D: of course it is also valid, but why would you prefer it that way?

Comment: I prefer to use classes as have had problems using just a tag. But as @Paulie_D said both are valid HTML...

Comment: You have had problems using just a tag?

Answer (score 0):

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kTSs2/)

I added extra styles to the JSFiddle for presentation and proof, but the code works the same without.

Do this:

HTML

```
<body>
  <footer>Hi</footer>
</body>
```

CSS

```
html,body{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  marging:0;
}

footer{
  height:120px;
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a good **`full width`** and **`sticky to bottom`** (if you need) solution:

```
<div class="content">
    <!-- content here -->

    <div class="hfooter">
        <!-- For Content not to lay under the Footer -->
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
    <!-- footer content here -->
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.content {
    height: 100%;
}
.hfooter {
    height: 100px;
}
.footer {
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: -100px;
}
```

Hope it is that what you need)

**DEMO here**: http://jsfiddle.net/verber/63gbg/11/

Answer (score 0):

### Block level elements

To understand this issue you need to understand about display:block. Block level elements (elements which declare display:block) by default take up the full width of their containing element.

In this case, the footer is, in all newish browsers, a block level element, and so will take up the full width of its container, in this case the body. There is no need to set width:100%;

### Older browsers

In older browsers, the newer HTML5 elements, including block, are inline by default, so you need to set them to be block level in your CSS, like so:

```
footer {
  display:block;
}
```

This is good practice.

### Floats

There are several things which can get in the way of this behaviour, notably floats. If you float an element, to the left or right, it will become as narrow as it possibly can, while still enclosing it’s contents. This may or may be your issue here.

Do please post your code.

Answer (score 0):

set footer width to viewport width `width: 100vw;`, and add the viewport meta tag to your header:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

Comment: This will work in the case of a responsive design viewed on a device. Was this the meaning of the original question?

Comment: The viewport tag will only be read by mobile devices. Desktop browsers will ignore it. This metatag is used to trigger a responsive design.

Comment: I disagree with you .. it works on desktop browsers, I used it several times

Comment: It sets the initial zooming factor for a device using virtual pixels (pinch to zoom). What possible use could it have on a desktop browser?